# more than one instance of singleton c#

Tags: c#, singleton

Is there a realisation of a Singleton-like pattern which allows to create more than one instance?

My class definition is:

```
public class Logger
{
    private Logger(string logPath)
    {
        this.logPath = logPath;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates singleton 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Logger GetInstance(string logPath)
    {
        lock (instanceLock)
        {
            if (logger == null)
            {
                logger = new Logger(logPath);
            }
        }
        return logger;
    }

    public static Logger Instance()
    {
        return logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Destructor
    /// </summary>
    ~Logger()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `LoggerFactory`? By the way, implement `IDisposable` interface

Comment: Not sure what the point is here, it looks like you're just providing a wrapper for an instance of a class?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "a Singleton-like pattern which allows more than once instance." I think that's called just "a regular class that doesn't follow the Singleton pattern."

Comment: A singleton that lets you create multiple instances is just a class.

Comment: You're confusing an equated definition of `static` with **Singleton**, and what you're actually describing is a **Factory**.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a singleton, but then create multiple instances.  It sounds more like a factory that will return an instance.  If you are looking for a specific instance, I suppose the factory could keep track of them and you can have a string key that identifies it, but I don't know if I would recommend the factory keeping track of the instances it puts out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pattern I use:

```
public class Logger
{
    private Logger(...) { ... }

    static Logger { /* initialize Errors, Warnings */ }

    public static Logger Errors { get; private set; }
    public static Logger Warnings { get; private set; }

    public void Write(string message) { ... }
}
```

If you want to have a `static Logger Lookup(string name)` method, you can do that too.

Now in other code you can write `Logger.Errors.Write("Some error");` or `Logger.Warnings.Write("Some warning");`.

**Bonus:** you can use `Environment.StackTrace` inside of your `Write` method to additionally log what method you called `Write` from.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a realisation of a Singleton-like pattern which allows to create more than one instance.

If you want multiple instances, just allow the class to be constructed directly, and don't make it a singleton.  In your case, just make the constructor public, and remove the singleton/instance logic.

That being said, there is the [Multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern), which allows keyed access to multiple instances via a single interface.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Hard to know - not enough details in the original question to know what's needed.  I mentioned Multiton since that ~could~ make sense in a logging type of class to allow access to different "logger" targets.

Comment: yes, I just thought he uses `string` as a key to intances, so it's hard to know what are the exact amount of instances should be populated beforehand. Also he uses some resources and it would be great, if these where managed by a `pool` not by a user

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern i use for multiple singletons.

```
public sealed class CCTalk
{

    public string Port { get; set; }
    private CCTalk(string port)
    {
        this.Port = port;
    }
    private static Dictionary<string, CCTalk> _instances = new Dictionary<string, CCTalk>();

    public static CCTalk GetPortInstance(string port)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port)) return null;

        if (!_instances.ContainsKey(port))
        {
            _instances.Add(port, new CCTalk(port));
        }
        return _instances[port];
    }
}
```